# How to associate request/response logs in .NET

Tags: .net, azure, logging, azure-application-insights, ilogger

pretty common scenario:

```cs
class MyServiceClient 
{
   ILogger<MyServiceClient> _logger;

   async Task Foo(Dto data)
   {
      _logger.LogDebug("Invoked API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = nameof(Foo), Data = data }); 

      var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data))

      var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

      string responseStr = httpResponse.ReadAsStringAsync()
      if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
      {
           _logger.LogError("Failed API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = nameof(Foo), ResponseData = responseStr }); 
      }

   }
}
```

1. How do I associate the request ("Invoked API") and response ("Failed API") logs? \not that I'm using app insights logger.
2. Is it possible to associate dependency logs (logs produces by http client) with this "operation"?

Comment: Have you considered generating a Guid, and then using that same guid in both log statements? You could call it a RequestContextId, RequestCorrelationId or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ILogger` implementation to create a Scope with some properties that will be attached to all telemetry generated by calls to the logger:

```cs
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"CorrelationId", Guid.NewGuid()}
}))
{
    _logger.LogWarning("Some Warning");
    _logger.LogInformation("Some Info");
}
```

`CorrelationId` will be in the `customDimensions` field of the trace telemetry in Application Insights.

But, if you want to correlate also the dependency request you can use the [`TelemetryClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#get-a-telemetryclient-instance) directly and explicitly create an operation that will be used to correlate all generated telemetry within the scope of that operation:

```cs
using (var operation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("Foo"))
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Invoked API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = nameof(Foo), Data = data });

    var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data))

    var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

    string responseStr = httpResponse.ReadAsStringAsync()
    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = nameof(Foo), ResponseData = responseStr });
    }
}
```

You can take this even further and set properties of the telemetry to reflect whether the call was succesful or not:

```cs
...

    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed API {ApiName}", new { ApiName = nameof(Foo), ResponseData = responseStr });
        operation.Telemetry.Success = false; 
    }

...
```

But do mind that if you are building a .Net Web App there already might be an request operation in progress, and by looking up that request telemetry you might discover that the trace telemetry and dependencies are already associated by the request.

Comment: Blazor Server uses websockets instead traditional http request/response => no usefull request telemery.

Comment: Follow up question: System.Net.Http doesn't reference ApplicationInsights. How it produces DependecyTelemetry?

Comment: @Liero see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#how-automatic-dependency-monitoring-works) on what methods are used by the DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule

Comment: @Liero Blazor, ok. You can also do `_telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>` to simulate a request, the outgoing http requests will then be logged as a DependencyTelemetry associated with the request.